# Remove Figure label in "List of Figures"

Tags: table-of-contents, classicthesis

I'm using [classicthesis](https://code.google.com/p/classicthesis/) of André Miede and I have the following list of figures:[image: List of figures]

I don't really like the sequence of *Figure* words (I think it's redundant) and I'm wondering if there's a way to keep only the numbering plus the caption.

Like this:

> LIST OF FIGURES
>
> ---
>
> 2.1 caption
>   2.2 caption
>   2.3 caption
>   and so on...

Same thing with listings and tables. In chapters, instead, I think it's ok to have "Figure", "Listing" and so on.

I'm not handy with LaTeX so I don't know where to start and even if it's possible!

Comment: Did i ever mention that i hate `classicthesis`  because it is a very bad template and should vanish from the face of the earth? Please remove line `\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename~}%Fig.~}` from the package file. 

For the tables, remove `\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\tablename~}%Tab.~}`

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for your help! I prefered to override the command how Harish Kumar suggested than totally deleting it. If you know some other nice template, please share it! =D

Comment: I got a little paranoid with `classicthesis`. There are so many question popping up wanting to revert stuff the template set up or reporting bugs where the template messed up. What *features* are you using right now?

Comment: What do you mean with _features_? I'm just writing, but so far I exclude what I asked in this question and the parts division of the work. I set up the floats with a per-chapter numbering and I'm doubtful about making dotted TOCs.

Comment: I bet you would be very satisfied with the standard `scrbook` or `scrreprt` if you were just searching for *latex template* on google. The TOC looks different, the fonts are different and the margins are. But you can be sure that nothing in the backround messes up.

Comment: Are they document classes like `book` or `memoir`? By the way, so far nothing messed up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20471/discussion-between-johannes-b-and-boh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{}` to your code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[floatperchapter]{classicthesis}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{}
\begin{document}
  \listoffigures
  \chapter{Chapter}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{A figure}
  \end{figure}
  \chapter{Chapter}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{A figure}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]